# Overriding methods in Java

Tags: java, overriding

Let

```
public class A{
    public MyType myMethod(){...}
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public MyType myMethod(){...}
}
```

be an arbitrary classes. Why MyType must be a parent type of MyAdvancedType necessarily? What happened if we permitted that MyAdvancedType can be an arbitrary type?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Where is the MyAdvancedType that you are talking about?

Comment: Why must `MyType` be anything? Are these supposed to be generic methods?

Comment: Do you novice in Java? In this case you must read about inheritance, polymorphism and interfaces in Java

Comment: What is `MyAdvancedType?` Not mentioned in your homework?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you meant MyAdvancedType in the second example

There is a simple explanation You have the following LOC:

```
A a = new B();
```

Now, when you try to call `myMethod` on the object a, in fact, you will call the overriden in the `B` class method.

Now, the overriden method returns an object of `MyAnvancedType`, but you called the method on the class `A`, which means all you know is you can get an object of `MyType`. So, the JVM casts `MyAnvancedType` to `MyType`, and you are gonna work with `MyType` object, even not suspecting that you are working with `MyAdvancedType`

And answering your second question. Even if the compiler permit you use an arbitrary type, you would get `ClassCastException`, as the compiler would try to cast `MySomeOtherType` to `MyType`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you:

*Why MyType must be a parent type of MyAdvancedType necessarily?*

Because you itself write `MyAdvancedType` as child of `MyType` (`class  B` is child of `class A` from your sample) and java ideology allow only one parent.

*What happened if we permitted that MyAdvancedType can be an arbitrary type*

Java recognize your `MyAdvancedType` as next types: `Object`, `MyType` and `MyAdvancedType`.
For example In this case:

```
class A{
    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("Class A method");
    }
}
class B extends A{}
...
A var = new B();
var.someMethod();
```

executed method of class A. But in this case:

```
class B extends A{
    @Overide //This string is optionally but good practice.
    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("Class B method");
    }
}
...
A var = new B();
var.someMethod();
```

executed overridden method of class B. This behavior be called `polymorphism`.